# Sending data from table to servlet through AJAX via POST request

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP with a table and once the 'submit' button is pressed I would like to send all the information from the table to a servlet through AJAX via POST request.

I have set up the request and response via the servlet and it is tested and working for a few variables.

However, I would like to know, whats the best way to send a lot of information, i.e. information from the table? The table could have 30-40 rows with each row having three columns. I need to preserve the information for each row since each row is processed independently of the others.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know, whats the best way to send a lot of information through AJAX

You can use [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) to send the table data that contains records one for each row. You can use various [JSON](http://json.org/) or [XML](http://www.xml.com/) parsing library to form java object back from JSON or XML string and vice-verse.

You can use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and [JSON](http://json.org/) library for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

While adding the rows you can create the tree kind of structure in the frontend. That could be some thing like this :

Each row will be an object and it has three attribute eg :

```
var rows_data = {firstName:"amit", lastName:"kumar", age:28};
```

Keep adding this rows into the array using javascript.

```
var rowArray= []; rowArray.push(rows_data);
```

While posting you can post this javascript array and from the servlet iterate the list and process the results.

Hope it helps to solve your problem.

Comment: How would I then process this in doPost Java method?